# how to write dyanamic select query statement with where clause in lovs management of SPAGOBI server

Tags: mysql

I need to write simple select statement with where clause dynamically in List of values(Lovs management) of SpagoBI server.

And I want to know how to set profile Attribute in SpagoBI server.

Can any one help me..?

Answer (score 0):

Create dataSource in spagoBi first then create the query in the dataset.In the dataset you can set the dynamic feature with the parameter see help in dataset for it then you can preview the dataset with preview option in it. You can use this dataset in any cockpit or document build in server.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: @Amruth Basav.please upvote or if you find useful please set it to useful